# PostgreSQL 8.2 unsupported version (1.11) in file header message to do backup restore

Tags: database, postgresql, database-restore, postgresql-8.2

I'm trying to restore a backup in postgreSQL pgAdmin and I get the following error message:

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.2\bin\pg_restore.exe -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d gsan_comercial -v "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\GSAN\Data Base\gsan_comercial_pmss.backup"
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.11) in file header

Process returned exit code 1.

I can not find the reason for this.

Tks

Comment: Are you sure the dump was done with 8.2 tools? 1.11 smells of 8.4 to me.

Comment: 8.2 itself is also unsupported since quite a while. You should plan your upgrade to 9.x as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version you find in the dump file header is related to the version of the *tools* used to do the dump, i.e., `pg_dump`. It is possible to dump an 8.2 database using `pg_dump` from a later version (for example one from the 8.4 distribution) because all tools are backward compatible but in the end you'll get a file that can only be restored using the new tools.

I suppose that is what happened and you're now trying to restore an 8.2 dump done using 8.4 tools on a pgAdmin using 8.2 tools.